# Changing file permissions for remote desktop connections

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, file-permissions

I frequently connect to a remote machine on Windows using [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Connection#Remote_Desktop_Connection). Both my local machine and the remote machine run `Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise`.

I would like the remote machine to be able to **write** on the drives it mounts from the local machine.

There is an option in the `Options`->`Local Resources tab` to enable the mounting of local drives, but when I connect to the remote machine, the remote machine cannot write  on the mounted local drives.

Are these the default permissions for remote desktop connections? Is there a way to change them?

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are *exactly* the same as those your local account has. If you are running Remote Desktop client as a normal user, then you will only have write access to your own files; the remote account is irrelevant.

If you want full access to the entire filesystem, run Remote Desktop (`mstsc`) as an administrator and with elevated privileges.

Comment: How would running the Remote Desktop Client as Admin give you admin privileges on the server you're connecting to?

Comment: @Luke: Like I said, the privileges you have on the server are irrelevant. You're writing to a local drive, whether directly or via remote desktop mount, so only local privileges matter.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question